# I want to ping a location on google map which is by redirecting from my app

Tags: java, android

I just want to ping a location on google map, means it need to show the red pin on google map, but the below code is navigating to the address which is specified their. How to ping a location without opening navigate bar.

```
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opening Google Maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=12.7634331,77.6543488"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:12.7634331,77.6543488");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
  startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```